# How to handle errors and terminate Goroutine using WaitGroup

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have been playing around with Goroutines, Channels and WaitGroup today and I am finally starting to understand the concept, after just been reading about it for a while.

My problem is that I am unsure how I handle errors when working like this, mainly because of the WaitGroup I use. When using the WaitGroup, I start by adding the amount of goroutines that will be executed, but what if an error happens during one of these?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "sync"
)

var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)

    waitGroup.Add(10)

    go doSomething(c)

    waitGroup.Wait()
}

func doSomething(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        n, err := someFunctionThatCanError()

        if err != nil {
            // How do I end the routines and WaitGroups here?
        }

        c <- n
        waitGroup.Done()
    }

    close(c)    
}

func someFunctionThatCanError() (int, error) {
    return 1, errors.New("an error")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZLsBSqdMD49

I have tried my best to provide an example that shows what I am talking about.  A loop will run 10 times in `doSomething()` and it will call `waitGroup.Done()` on every iteration, but what if an error happens during all this, like shown with `someFunctionThatCanError()`?

When I try to solve it now, by returning and/or cancelling the channel, I end up with deadlocks, so I am a little unsure where to go from here. I am also unsure of how to handel the WaitGroup that I assume is waiting for more things to happen.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Use sync.WaitGroup to manage the goroutines, not the tasks within the goroutines.  Change `waitGroup.Add(10)`  to `waitGroup.Add(1)`. Add  `defer waitgroup.Done()` to the beginning of `doSomething` and remove other calls to `waitgroup.Done()` from `doSomething`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [golang.org/x/sync/errgroup](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) to wait on and handle errors from goroutines.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)

    var g errgroup.Group

    g.Go(func() error {
        return doSomething(c)
    })

    // g.Wait waits for all goroutines to complete
    // and returns the first non-nil error returned
    // by one of the goroutines.
    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func doSomething(c chan int) error {
    defer close(c)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        n, err := someFunctionThatCanError()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        c <- n
    }
    return nil
}

func someFunctionThatCanError() (int, error) {
    return 1, errors.New("an error")
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/756nlaIXeU3).

Comment: That sub repo has better primitives then the core library. Shame they didn't mention in the tour.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `sync.WaitGroup` is not used anywhere but it's defined, is it needed?